# How does bluetooth host know which HID to use and how does UUID work?

Tags: bluetooth, hid

I have spent hours reading up on bluetooth (classic, not BLE) and i still have some questions i found conflicting answers on the internet.

1. What is the UUID in bluetooth? is the UUID a unique ID for the service the bluetooth device provides (which means it can have multiple) , or is it a globally unique ID for the bluetooth device so that other device can connect to each other? If its the latter, dont bluetooth device connect to each other using Mac addresses?
2. After a client connects to a server device, how does the server know the client is a keyboard  and hence a the keyboard driver is needed to be run and to handle data coming from there? Is it because of the sdp_record.xml in the peripheral device is presented to the server at the service discovery phase and it contains information of what HID driver to use? And there is a universal standard on what hexa value would trigger which key when sent across bluetooth?

Comment: I would imagine the keyboard tells the computer that it's a keyboard during the initial handshaking, but I don't know anything about bluetooth so I can't say for sure.